# enumerate() for sliced list does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

enumerate() for a list works as expected.

```
def swap(nums, i, j):
    temp = nums[i]
    nums[i] = nums[j]
    nums[j] = temp

mylist = [0,1,22,33,4]

for pos, num in enumerate(mylist):
    print(pos,num)
    if pos == 0:
        swap(mylist,2,3)
```

In this example, `num` shows swapped value as expected.

```
0 0
1 1
2 33 <--
3 22 <-- 
4 4
```

But if I change `mylist` to `mylist[:-1]` like:

```
def swap(nums, i, j):
    temp = nums[i]
    nums[i] = nums[j]
    nums[j] = temp

mylist = [0,1,22,33,4]

for pos, num in enumerate(mylist[:-1]):
    print(pos,num)
    if pos == 0:
        swap(mylist,2,3)
```

`num` does not show swapped value.

```
0 0
1 1
2 22 <--
3 33 <--
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that you are enumerating on a *copy* of the list. In your first example, you are enumerating on a direct reference to the list that you are altering, but in the second example, you used slicing on the list to enumerate over. Slicing returns a new list object.

This is important because you are altering what not-yet-iterated-over positions are referencing to. List iteration uses an ever-increasing *index* to yield values, altering the list as you iterate can mean that a next index references a different value.

That the iteration is done via the `enumerate()` function doesn't really matter. You'd have the same problem without `enumerate()`:

```
for num in mylist:
    print(num)
    if num == 0:
        swap(mylist, 2, 3)
```

would print

```
0
1
33
22
4
```

and slicing would give you a copy, so:

```
for num in mylist[:-1]:
    print(num)
    if num == 0:
        swap(mylist, 2, 3)
```

outputs

```
0
1
22
33
```

If the goal is to skip the last element, then instead of creating a copy through slicing, you could use the enumerated position to break out of the loop early:

```
for pos, num in enumerate(mylist):
    if pos == len(mylist) - 1:
        break
    print(pos, num)
    if pos == 0:
        swap(mylist, 2, 3)
```

or you can use the [`itertools.islice()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
from itertools import islice

for pos, num in enumerate(islice(mylist, len(mylist) - 1)):
    print(pos, num)
    if pos == 0:
        swap(mylist, 2, 3)
```

or you could simply create your copy *first*, then alter the indices of that copy:

```
sliced = mylist[:-1]
for pos, num in enumerate(sliced):
    print(pos, num)
    if pos == 0:
        swap(sliced, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem doesn't come from the `enumerate` function.

Actually, when doing `mylist[:-1]` you are creating a **new** list, and working on it.

So when you try to modify your list (`swap(mylist,2,3)`), you modify the original one, not the new one (created by `mylist[:-1]`).

You can solve your problem by doing:

```
new_list = mylist[:-1]
for pos, num in enumerate(new_list):
    print(pos,num)
    if pos == 0:
        swap(new_list,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`mylist[:-1]` is creating a new list object but you perform swap using `mylist`.

**How do you know it's a different object?**

You can test this behaviour using `id()`:

```
>>> mylist = [0,1,22,33,4,5]
>>> id(mylist)
3954492760
>>> lst = mylist
>>> id(lst)
3954492760
>>> sliced = mylist[:-1]
>>> id(sliced)
3954492920
```

If you observe, `sliced`'s id is different.

---

Now coming to your code:

```
for pos, num in enumerate(mylist[:-1]):
    print(pos,num)
    if pos == 0:
        swap(mylist,2,3)
#              ^^^ - you used a different list object from what you were iterating over.
```

The **easiest** fix you can do is slice beforehand:

```
sliced = mylist[:-1]
for pos, num in enumerate(sliced):
    print(pos,num)
    if pos == 0:
        swap(sliced,2,3)
```

So as others mentioned this has nothing to do with `enumerate`.